# В отдельном классе записать ресурсы в массив строк

Tags: android, массивы, строки, ресурсы

Есть отдельно вынесенный класс по работе с базой данных:

```
public class DB
{
private final Context mCtx;
private DBHelper mDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

public DB(Context ctx)
{
    mCtx = ctx;
}
```

Во вложенном классе по созданию и управлению БД

```
private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
```

присутствует метод

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
```

в котором создаются таблицы и вносятся первоначальные данные из объявленных и заполненных здесь же массивов. С целью возможности перевода я вынес строковые названия в файл ресурсов strings.xml

```
// значения первоначальных данных в БД
<string name="task_1">Сон</string>
<string name="task_2">Еда</string>
```

Теперь архангелы Андроида не дают мне получить доступ к ресурсам:

```
 String Arr_NAME[] = {getResources().getString(R.string.task_1), "Еда", "Прогулка", "Дорога"};
```

При попытке заменить первый пункт ссылкой на ресурсы - гетРесурсы - выделено красным и не могут они, дескать, реализовать этот метод. Так же не работает и просто getString(R.string.task_1) и R.string.task_1. Естественно, в обычном public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity таких сложностей не возникает, и строковое значение можно получить String X = getString(R.string.task_1).
Как же правильно по святым письменам взять ресурсы и поместить в массив в отдельно стоящем классе?

Comment: попробуйте context.getStringg

Comment: context - то же красный, и не "резолв".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методы `getResourses()` и `getString()` относятся к классу `Context`.

Так что вам надо получить ссылку на контекст (например передав её через конструктор вашего класса) и на нём эти методы вызывать.

В вашем конкретном случае `Context` содержится в переменной вашего класса с именем  `mCtx`. Значит надо писать так:

```
mCtx.getResources(); и mCtx.getString(R.string.SOME_STRING);
```

Comment: Юрий, для меня контекст в андроиде, несмотря на потраченные дни и ночи, так и остался "слишком абстрактным объектом", чтобы самостоятельно творчески применять. Я добавил в вопросе код с контекстом для своего класса. Буду признателен, если Вы предложите конкретный код.

Comment: @St-st, см. обновлённый ответ

Comment: Грант Мерси!!!!

Answer (score 2):

И правильно.
если вы хотите обратиться к ресурсам из любого места в приложении, Создайте класс по примеру

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static App mInstance;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static App getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

и добавьте в манифест

```
 <application
        android:name=".App"
          ...
        <activity
         ........
```

после чего можно обратиться к ресурсам так `App.getInstance().getResources().getString(R.string.task_1)`

Либо передавайте `Context` в конструкторе.

Comment: Создавать класс по первому варианту, все же, нецелесообразно только ради доступа к ресурсу. А вот вторая идея через конструктор и была реализована. Благодарю.

Comment: этот класс открывает массу возможностей =)

Comment: Перечислите, пожалуйста, эти возможности.

Comment: Данный класс стартует первым, как только вы нажали на иконку приложения. А значит он будет создан до того, как вы увидите первый экран вашего приложения. В этом классе удобно инициализировать библиотеки, открывать и закрывать базу и многое другое. Зависит от ваших потребностей.